# Which of these are win phone 8 templates?

Tags: windows-phone-8

So I have, among other things, XNA 4, windows 7.1 sdk, windows 8 sdk windows phone 7 sdk and windows phone 8 sdk.

So in Visual studio 2010 I see the following, which I assume are all Windows Phone 7.x,

[image]

Windows phone 8 SDK requires Visual Studio 2012, so here is what I see in Visual Studio 2012. Can anyone confirm these are the Windows phone 8 templates?

[image]

I'm slightly confused because I wasn't expecting to see XAML in the same breath as DirectX or XNA for that matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All those templates will work with Windows Phone 8. Some of those are compatible with Windows Phone 7 as well (like "Windows Phone App"), in which case Visual Studio will ask you at creation time if you want to target WP7 or WP8.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm slightly confused because I wasn't expecting to see XAML in the same breath as DirectX or XNA for that matter.

I wasn't, since that's what the Windows Phone Division shipped ;-) Yes, you're seeing the correct templates on the second screenshot (from VS2012)

Comment: Well, after all the discussion about the future of XNA, and the suggestion that XNA would only be a legacy option with no access to Windows Phone 8 APIs, etc etc :)

Comment: Plenty of wrong/useless rumours out there. People should just have shutted their mouth, and waited for us to release the SDK.